# How to reset asset path by Python

Tags: 3dsmax

I can get all the asset names and paths, but I don't know how to modify them. Who knows how to do it? It's better to use Python or maxscript.

Answer (score 0):

For example

```
assetData = getMAXFileAssetMetadata filePath

for asset in assetData do
    asset.filename = substituteString asset.filename original replacement

setMAXFileAssetMetadata filePath assetData
```

Python version would be pretty much the same, only with `pymxs.runtime.` prefix for the functions.